# Will MVA work with text fields in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I am indexing an id from a look-up-table in my `sphinx configuration`.

```
sql_attr_multi = uint customer_type_id from ranged-query; \
SELECT f.orderID AS ID, f.typeID \
FROM LUT_customerType f \
WHERE f.orderID BETWEEN \$start AND \$end \
ORDER BY f.orderID; \
SELECT MIN(orderID), MAX(orderID) FROM LUT_customerType
```

this returns, for example, in a given field:

`customer_type_id: 3,5.15`

As the LUT table simply stores `orderID` and `typeID`

However, I now want to index the Type Name (I was using MySql to query it but this will be more efficient I hope).

I tried doing this:

```
sql_joined_field = customer_type_name from ranged-query; \
SELECT f.orderID AS ID, n.Name \
FROM LUT_customerType f \
INNER JOIN customerType_Names n ON f.typeID= n.ID \
AND f.orderID BETWEEN \$start AND \$end \
ORDER BY f.orderID; \
SELECT MIN(orderID), MAX(orderID) FROM LUT_customerType
```

In other words, I replicated the working `MVA` `Select` with two minor changes:

1. I added an additional join to get the Type Name
2. I removed the unit since I didn't want this to be an integer

I tried the `Select` in MySql and it works as expected.

Yet neither the field nor values show up, not in individual records when selecting from `SphinxQL`

```
`Select * from idx_Table`
```

Nor when checking the Sphinx Index Structure

```
`Desc idx_Table`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `sql_joined_field` is making a **Field** ... fields are full-text searchable fields.

THey are NOT stored in the index, in such a way they can be 'retrieved' (only used in queries).

**Attributes** on the other hand, like MVA, *are* retrievable, as they stored by document-id.

Sphinx doesn't have a Multi-Value *String* Attribute, or even scalar string Attribute that can be built with a 'query' (like mva/joined-field).

if want a joined string attribute use `GROUP_CONCAT` mysql aggregation function, in the main `sql_query` - along with a `GROUP BY`

(`sql_attr_multi` can also parse a comma seperated string, eg built with GROUP_CONCAT from a field in the main `sql_query`. So can build both the mva and joined-string-attribute, in the main query, without needing seperate query)

---

For example...

```
sql_query = SELECT o.orderID, description, \
    GROUP_CONCAT(f.typeID) as customer_type_id, \
    GROUP_CONCAT(n.Name SEPERATOR ' ' ORDER BY n.ID) AS customer_type_name \
    FROM orders o \
    LEFT JOIN LUT_customerType f ON (f.orderID = o.orderID) \
    LEFT JOIN customerType_Names n ON (f.typeID= n.ID) \
    GROUP BY o.orderID \
    ORDER BY NULL 

sql_attr_multi = uint customer_type_id from field;

sql_field_string = customer_type_name
```

(could use `sql_attr_string` instead, if only want attribute, dont actully want it as a field too)

... in practice, possibly make it a ranged query too, like your small query was.

Also note the ORDER BY inside the GROUP_CONCAT. As sphinx will internall reorder the MVA into numerical order, this ensures that the text attribute has the same ordering.

Comment: @BaryHunter Thanks for the great insights. To be clear the sql_query you show is not a new addition to the index but should be incorporated into my (already quite complex :) ) main sql_query select

Comment: Yes. Thats just a demo, yes, would need to add stuff to the main query.

Comment: Thanks Barry. I decided to just do a MysQl using the mva values as the entire rest of the record is sphinx. I hate to add a MySql request but it is small and adding 10-15 of the above to an already complex sql-query which has multiple other joins just doesn't seem worth the debugging headache. It IS goog to know however.